# Python Dictionaries For loops

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "category": "coin",
        "is_hidden": 0
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Litecoin",
        "symbol": "LTC",
        "category": "coin",
        "is_hidden": 0..................
```

I'm having issues looping through this structure......

This does not work:

```
 for x in metadata['data']:
    for y in x:
```

Comment: The 2nd should be: `for y in metadata['data'][x]:`

Answer (score 1):

By default, iteration on dictionaries in Python iterates over the keys, in order to be consistent with the way the `in` operator works. So your `x` variable is taking on the values `"1"` and `"2"`. If you only care about the values, you can do

```
for x in metadata['data'].values():
    ...
```

If you need both the keys and the values, you can do

```
for k, x in metadata['data'].items():
    ...
```

In this example, `k` will take on the values `"1"` and `"2"`, while `x` will be the dictionaries associated to those keys.

Comment: Very simple, got lost in the structure, didn't think abut the values clause.  Many thanks!

Comment: One question:   After this loop, using .values(), is that data still considered a "dictionary"?   I need to rename some keys, and this is not working:   metadata['urls_technical_doc'] = metadata.pop('technical_doc').    I get invalid key.    But it works for other structures, without the nested dictionary......

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. None of your example input has urls_technical_doc or technical_doc anywhere in it, so I can't really answer that